# Relative pronoun in sentences with emphasis

Tags: relative-pronouns, which-that

This sentence sounds wrong to my ear, and I would have used "that" instead of "which".

> So what is it about "preventative" **which** had usage commenters of earlier times foaming at the mouth? ([source](https://neverpureandrarelysimple.wordpress.com/2018/11/15/preventive-preventative/))

I don't know what this type of sentence is called. Sentences like "What is it that made you come?" "What is it that you don't understand?" "What is it about him that is bad?" "How is it that he didn't know?" all seem to require "that" not "which", as far as I understand.

What is this type of sentence called? And am I right in thinking the sentence at issue needs a "that" instead of "which"? Why?

Comment: Have you looked at [any of these which vs that questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=which+or+that)?

Comment: I agree. The question is "What is it... that had commenters foaming at the mouth?" The clause isn't a description of the word _preventative_.

Comment: Both forms are fine in your first example, though I suspect that many speakers would prefer the subordinator "that" to the relative pronoun "which".

Comment: The overarching 'rules' for non-hyperprescriptivists are that (2)'**which** _must_ be used with non-defining relative clauses' and (1) '**that** is _preferred_ with defining (ie identifier) relative clauses'. [usually listed in the reverse order, hence my numbering] But I'd say that you've come across an example where the pull towards '**that** for an identificational† relative clause' [†this particular attribute/association of 'preventative': the one that had usage commenters of earlier times foaming at the mouth] is encouraging many to step momentarily closer to the prescriptivist stance.

Comment: It's ironic that this mistake was made in a web site about language usage. But I'm sure most of us have made wording mistakes in comments and answers here, too.